# Looking for example of function between metric spaces such that...

Tags: real-analysis

$f: X \to Y$ is continuous and $E \subset Y$

such that

$f^{-1}(\overline{E}) \not\subset \overline{f^{-1}(E)}$

any tips of what to try?

Comment: D'oh, misread as $\subsetneq$. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Arrange matters so that $E$ is not in the range of $f$, but $E$ has at least one limit point that **is** in the range of $f$.

Comment: Oh that makes it much easier and explains why I had so much difficulty before . Is this the only way to find such an example?

Comment: @user95041: Pretty much: if $E\subseteq f[X]$, the two sets are actually equal.